# How do I redirect all writes and reads from /sdcard/whatsapp/ to /sdcard/shared/ on android?

Tags: io-redirection, android

I am using bluestacks appplayer beta with a rooted android, I want to redirect all writes and reads from one directory to another, how do I do that? I have a terminal available to put commands in..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a bind mount (use `busybox mount` if the built-in `mount` does not support the `--rbind` option)

```
mount --rbind  /sdcard/shared /sdcard/whatsapp
```

You need to call this command on each reboot.

For a permanent solution, you can also replace the directory with a soft/hard link to the target directory:

```
mv /sdcard/whatsapp /sdcard/whatsapp_old    #rename if needed
ln -s /sdcard/shared /sdcard/whatsapp
```

Comment: when the /sdcard/WhatsApp folder doesn't exist I get the error file does not exist (/sdcard/shared exists) and when I create an empty whatsapp folder in sdcard then it says link failed because file already exists, this is very confusing, what to do? (when doing the permanent solution)

Comment: Update, retried and I get link operation not permitted.. :o

Comment: Does the target folder need to be something other than NTFS? It's NTFS currently

Comment: fixed :P forgot su